# Activerecord has_many :through through multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to access all comments from a given user with `user.comments`. The query is to go through two different models, which likely both return results. My relations are set up as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organisers
  has_many :participants
  has_many :comments, through: :participants / :organisers (see explenation below)
end

class Organiser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Participant  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organiser
  belongs_to :participant
end
```

A comment is validated to belong to either a participant, or an organiser.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I've tried

```
has_many :comments, through: :participants
has_many :comments, through: :organisers
```

and

```
has_many :comments, through: [:organisers, :participants]
```

But that last one isn't rails. Is there a proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```rb
has_many :comments, ->(user) {
  unscope(where: :user_id).
  left_joins(:organizer, :participant).
  where('organizers.user_id = ? OR participants.user_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
}
```

The `unscope` is to remove the `comments.user_id = ?` clause (which is added by default when you define a `has_many` relation).
The `left_joins` is called on `Comment`, so you need to pass in the relation names as defined on `Comment`, hence the singulars in this example.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming across this using **polymorphic associations**, the following worked for me inspired by magni- and Carlos Jimenez' answers:

```
has_many :comments, -> (user) {
  unscope(where: :user_id).
  where(commentable: [user.organizers, user.participants])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution after many tries. You can use a scope with param in your last has_many sentence in the User model:

```
has_many :comments, -> (user) {where organiser: user.organisers}, through: :participants
```

The "user" param represet the User object whom is calling the comments method.

Answer (score 1):

Since we couldn't use `has_many, through` here because `comments` come from both of `organisers` and `participants`. I just think there are 2 solutions here:

**Solution #1** Define `comments` method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def comments
    Comment.joins([{organiser: :user}, {participant: :user}])
           .where(users: {id: self.id})
  end
end
```

So then your query to find comments is:

```
User.first.comments
```

**Solution #2** Use scope in `Comment`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :from_user, -> (user) { 
    joins([{organiser: :user}, {participant: :user}]).where(users: {id: user.id}) 
  }
end
```

So your query will be like:

```
user = User.first
comments = Comment.from_user(user)
```

Comment: I don't believe these solutions will work, as the `joins` statement effectively acts as an `AND` between the two supplied arguments, instead of the desired `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

> Since we couldn't use has_many, through here because comments come from both of organizers and participants. I just think there are 2 solutions here:

Basically you can still change the foreign key to accept the `self.id` automatically with Rails here

```
User.first.comments

class User
  has_many :comments, -> { joins([{ organiser: :user }, { participant: :user }]) }, through: :participants, foreign_key: "users.id"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe your associations would be confused, as user.comments wouldn't know whether it's going through Participant or Organiser, so the best option would be to declare two different joins (with different names):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Comment: Think of this request as asking for `user.participant_or_organizer_comments`