# ActiveRecord grab shared model from polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm looking for a better way to query Users from 2 different Models used in a polymorphic association. Here is the setup

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :announcement

  has_many :targets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists, through: :targets, source: :target, source_type: 'List'
  has_many :accounts, through: :targets, source: :target, source_type: 'Account'
end
```

```
class Target < ApplicationRecord
  # belongs_to :announcement
  belongs_to :schedule
  belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true

  delegate :announcement, to: :schedule

end
```

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :targets, as: :target, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lists_users
  has_many :users, through: :lists_users
end
```

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :announcements, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :targets, as: :target, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

end
```

At the moment I'm solving this by creating a method inside the Schedule model that grabs Users this way:

```
  def subscribers
    targets.map(&:target).map(&:users).flatten.uniq
  end
```

I looked at something similar with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749740/activerecord-has-many-through-through-multiple-models), but didn't seem to solve it.

Comment: Where is the second model which is used in the polymorphic association?

Comment: Do you expect the `targets.map(&:target)` collection to include instances of different classes or does it only have to include `Account` instances?

Comment: Correct, targets.map(&:target) would be a collection of Account and List objects, both of those objects have users. Then end product is to end up with a collection of User objects, based off users in Account and users in List

Comment: You should add `has_many :targets, as: :target` in `List` as well for it to be understood

Comment: Edited to show List with has_many association. Maybe I'm not understanding the concept correctly or I'm using it wrong, but if I'm needing to call Schedule.targets and turn that collection in to their respective Models so I can then grab the users associated with them, why would I need the has_many also in List?


If you look at Schedule model you can see both Account and List being used as the polymorphic associations

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the associations in the Schedule model, so it was hard to understand what was the second polymorphic association.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that like this:

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  def subscribers
    # fetch all associated user IDs
    lists_user_ids = lists.joins(:lists_users).distinct.pluck("lists_users.user_id")
    accounts_user_ids = accounts.joins(:users).distinct.pluck("users.id")
    user_ids = (lists_user_ids + accounts_user_ids).uniq

    # fetch users by IDs
    User.where(id: user_ids)
  end
end
```